# How passing data to a button in vue native?

Tags: vue.js, native

I try to pass each button a title that is browsed in a loop. I have hard value, I can not get my true value.

I try this to passing to pass my variable like this to the title tag title

```
   <view v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="index">
          <button
          :title="post.name"
          color="#841584"
          />
      </view>
```

As a result in my buttons I have "post.name" and I want the true value of my loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to bind the button name from the for loop 
you can bind it like this

```
<button :title="post.name"
          color="#841584">{{post.name}}</button>
```